# What's the word for a word that suddenly becomes famous?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the right word for a word that suddenly becomes famous?

I know *buzzword*. Are there any similar words or common phrases, like *shot up word*?

My specific context is that I am looking for some suitable word for the heading title of a section which shows charts of words that have suddenly become hot and used a lot in the media (TV, magazines, radio, etc.).

Comment: I am actually making some website with graphs and charts, and was looking for some suitable word for the heading title of the section which shows charts of words that have suddenly become hot and used a lot in the media(TV, magazines, radio, etc..).

Comment: *Catchword* is often used to refer to a trendy word or phrase, but I am not sure if it can be used if a word has rose to be famous **suddenly**. Such as in, "Quality assurance is a *catchword* these days."

Comment: Do you have a single word in mind? Would a phrase be acceptable?

Comment: A phrase is fine.

Comment: Obviously, it's a *meme*!

Comment: *"Shot-up word"* does not work - that would be 'a word destroyed by gunfire.' ++Formally, they are "words that have rapidly gained popular currency" - Informally, they could be "trendy" words: OED - A. adj. *Fashionable, up to date, following the latest trend. (Sometimes dismissively.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider *trendy fads*.

It sounds like you are talking about the sort of annoying business jargon that shows up in Buzzword Bingo games, except that it is not limited to CorpSpeak.

Answer (score 0):

**vogue word**

Dictionary.com: [a word or term that is fashionable for a time](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vogue-word)

Wiktionary: [(linguistics) A neologism that gains sudden popularity but is forgotten after a relatively short time](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vogue_word)

Answer (score 0):

**'in' expression**

I can't find a dictionary entry for this one. "In" here is used in the sense "in fashion", meaning "popular".